# PHP - Email tracking blocked by Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, tracking

we have developed a tracking system for a web app developed by us.

This system works with an image tag written at the bottom of each mail, that points a php file where the mail is tracked.

Using a Gmail account, the image generate an error and with the browser inspector , the code of img tag hasn't the SRC attribute.

The image tag generated was this:

```
<img src="https://our.website.com/recordmail.php?mail=user-email" alt="Tracker" />
```

when in Gmail (with the browser inspector) the code of tag was this:

```
<img alt="Tracker" />
```

This is the "recordmail.php" script (create on fly 1x1 px gif file):

```
//first we make database tracking stuff then create image...
/* IN THIS POINT WORK WITH DATABASE */
.....    
header('Content-Type: image/gif');


header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );

header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );

echo base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==');

exit;
```

Someone have suggests how resolve this issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this after clicking "unblock images" in the client?

Comment: yes, in the settings there are checked "always display external images"

Comment: From reading around this issue: does adding a width and height as html attributes work? Or adding a alt and a title? Or all of these things?

Comment: Hi, I have added width , height and title attributes and the tracker seems to work correctly !!! Thank you!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer if you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to ensure images show in Gmail:

- Has the client enabled images for your email / all emails?
- Does the image src URI start with "https://" (or "http://")?
- Have you defined a `width` and `height` for the image?

[(Somewhat of a) source](https://css-tricks.com/dealing-content-images-email/)